# How to do command substitution in perl?

Tags: perl

Basically in shell will do command substution like this

```
a=`uname -a`
```

then how to do in perl?

Comment: sorry ..    a=\`uname -a\`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$a = qx( uname -a )
```

The `qx` operator is the same as backticks, but far more readable.

Comment: +1 `$a = qx( uname -a )` is equivalent to ```$a = `uname -a` ```

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty much identical in Perl -

```
$a = `uname -a`;
```

but, as [@William Purcell says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15113645/622310), `qx` is the same and more readable.