# Unable to perform desired substitution with backtick character

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I have a string with backticks:

```
this is `some` text
```

I want to precede the backticks with a backslash:

```
this is \`some\` text
```

I tried:

```
s/`/\`/g
```

but this resulted in the original text:

```
this is `some` text
```

and:

```
s/`/\\`/g
```

but this resulted in a double backslash:

```
this is \\`some\\` text
```

I've tried many other tricks but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second one should work...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;
my $string = "a string with `backticks` in it";
say "Before: $string";
$string =~ s/`/\\`/g;
say "After: $string";
```

produces

```
Before: a string with `backticks` in it
After: a string with \`backticks\` in it
```

Comment: Yup, that should. But I keep getting double backslashes. There's got to be something else going on with my code. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, dammit, was running the output through Dumper and it was escaping the backslash so it looked like a double backslash. There goes that hour.

Comment: @StevieD we've all been there.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in one-liner manner from a file **without Data::Dumper** :

```
perl -pe 's/\`/\\`/g' file
```

### Output

```
this is \`some\` text
```

Comment: Doesn't work in my script. That still results in \\\`some\\\`.

Answer (score 0):

Or using a one liner with `sed`

```
sed 's/[`]/\\\`/g' file
```

Explanation.

Use the *character class* `[...]` to protect the character you wish to substitute, and then use the POSIX form of escape `"\\"` to escape the actual `'\'` you wish to include in the substituted text.

Comment: I'm not on the command line. I'm trying to do this from within a perl script.

Comment: `sed` will read from a file or you can simply pipe `stdout` to it. (e.g. `echo 'this is \`some\` text' | sed 's/[`]/\\\\`/g'`)  (escaping backticks in comments is a bit tricky...) You can also use *command substitution*, e.g. [How to do command substitution in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113607/how-to-do-command-substitution-in-perl)

Comment: @StevieD, if you're looking specifically for a Perl (internal) solution, then remove the [bash] tag from your question -- it only confuses things.  It wouldn't hurt to clarify this in the question text, too.

Comment: oops, my bad. Thanks.